# Socket creating multiple data for a single request

Tags: angular, socket.io

i have written a socket.io code for real-time comments for a bug tracking tool. However if someone comments, same data is created multiple times. And i get same comments repeated.

Please see by socket.io code in nodejs below

```
socket.on('new-comment', (data)=>{
            data['commentId'] = shortid.generate()
            eventEmitter.emit('save-comment', data)
        }) // end of on new comment


        eventEmitter.on('save-comment', (data)=>{

            let newComment = new CommentModel({
                commentId: data.commentId,
                comment: data.comment,
                commentedBy: data.commentedBy,
                createdOn: time.now(),
                issueId: data.issueId
            })

            newComment.save((err, result)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(`Error occured: ${err}`)
                } else if(check.isEmpty(result)){
                    console.log("No Comments to be Saved")
                } else {
                    console.log("Comment saved")
                    console.log(result)
                }
            })
```

This is code in my socket service of angular to post a comment

```
public postComment: any = (commentDetails) =>{
    this.socket.emit('new-comment', commentDetails)
  } // end on new-comment
```

code in my component to handle this function

```
public postComment: any = () =>{
    if(this.comment){
      let userComment = {
        comment: this.comment,
        commentedBy: this.currentUser.firstName+' '+this.currentUser.lastName,
        createdOn: Date.now(),
        issueId: this.currentIssueId
      }
        this.socket.postComment(userComment)
        this.currentComments.push(userComment)
        this.watchersList.push(Cookie.get('fullName'))
    } else {
      this.toastr.errorToastr("Cannot post empty comments")
    }
  } // end post comment
```

let me know where i am going wrong